# I would like to check if a value of a column(x) is NaN an and change then the value of another column to 1

Tags: r

```
ds$status <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(ds)) {
  if (is.na(ds$survivaltimeind[i]))
  {ds$status[i] <- 1}}
```

If the value in (survivaltimeind) is NaN make the value of the same row of column status to 1
I would also be interested if there is any better option
Thanks in advance

Comment: No need for loops, try: `df$status <- as.integer(!is.nan(df$survivaltimeind))`

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse, you could do it like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

ds <- mutate(ds, status = is.na(survivaltimeind))
```

`status` is then a boolean flag where if `survivaltimeind` is NA then it is `TRUE`.